# PHPExcel codificación

Tags: php, phpexcel

Tengo el problema a la hora de mostrar un excel en diferentes entornos, en el entrono de desarrollo se ve todo correcto pero en producción y test se ven como si estuvieran encriptados. Lo que más me descuadra que hay otra aplicación igual alojada en el mismo servidor con la misma función y lo muestra bien, por lo que he descartado en encoding del servidor.
Uso la libreria PHPExcel y así es como está configurado.

```
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

    ///pruebas encoding
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    //header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=utf-8");
    //header('Content-type: application/x-msdownload; charset=utf-16');
    ///

    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$nombreFichero");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
```

Comment: Otro dato curioso que acabo de ver es que al crear el Excel donde me sale mal el nombre de la pestaña que se le da a la hoja recibe el nombre del fichero

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el Excel generado dándole a "Guardar como..."? Es probable que te haya salido algún tipo de advertencia o mensaje que al agregarse al principio del Excel corrompe su formato y probablemente ni se envíen las cabeceras por haber enviado texto al navegador con antelación.